# Where to put X11 drivers configuration in Ubuntu Lucid?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, x-server

Since hal is removed from Lucid, where now can I put all those little configuration tweaks for mouse and other input devices?

In particular, I want to configure ThinkPad trackpad to enable scrolling with middle button. In hal, it was done with

```
<match key="info.product" string="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint">
    <merge key="input.x11_options.EmulateWheel" type="string">true</merge>
    <merge key="input.x11_options.EmulateWheelButton" type="string">2</merge>
    <merge key="input.x11_options.ZAxisMapping" type="string">4 5</merge>
    <merge key="input.x11_options.XAxisMapping" type="string">6 7</merge>
    <merge key="input.x11_options.Emulate3Buttons" type="string">true</merge>
    <merge key="input.x11_options.EmulateWheelTimeout" type="string">200</merge>
</match>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the right place. It's `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. There's already some configuration files that can be used as examples but surprisingly `man xorg.conf` have good enough documentation about all new `Match` keywords.

The example from the post can be translated to the following snippet (in a file `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-trackpoint.conf`)

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Trackpoint"
    MatchProduct    "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option          "EmulateWheel" "true"
    Option          "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
    Option          "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
    Option          "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
    Option          "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option          "EmulateWheelTimeout" "200" 
    Option          
EndSection
```

**Note**: for Ubuntu 10.10 you should place your config files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf/` instead.